# How do I set JVM options for GradleWorkerMain?

Tags: java, jvm, gradle, bamboo

When I set `GRADLE_OPTS` or `JAVA_OPTS`, these are set for `GradleWrapperMain` when I run `./gradlew build` for my project.  But I need them to be set for `GradleWorkerMain` as well.

How do I do that?

Here's the `ps` listing when that Gradle job is running in Bamboo. My `JAVA_OPTS` (such as `-Dcool.opt=1`) is missing from `GradleWorkerMain`.

```
53854 ? Sl 2:13 /home/apps/jdk7/bin/java -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dcool.opt=1 -Xms1g -Xmx8g -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew -classpath /path/to/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain build
54272 ? Sl 0:19 /home/apps/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -cp /path/to/lots/of/jars.jar org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Which bigger problem are you trying to solve? Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: The reason is rather stupid in my case: GradleWorkerMain processes sometimes hang on my build server.  I'd like to have something to grep for when I kill it.  I can't just kill all GradleWorkerMain processes since this is a shared build server.  So a `-Dbamboo.buildKey=${bamboo.buildKey}` would do the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no direct way to set JVM options for a `GradleWorkerMain` process. Most (but not all) task types that fork new workers implement `JavaForkOptions`, so you could try:

```
tasks.withType(JavaForkOptions) {
    systemProperty "cool.opt", "1"
    jvmArgs "someArg"
}
```

Task types that don't implement `JavaForkOptions` typically allow to set fork options in some other way. For example:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true // otherwise won't fork
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs = ["-Dcool.opt=1"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One similar issue I've seen is with the gradle scala plugin. I needed to add the config below to control the Xmx.

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    configure(scalaCompileOptions.forkOptions) {
        memoryMaximumSize = '1g'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control it with:

```
test {
    maxHeapSize = "4g"
}
```